# JVM terminated. Exit code = -1 error while opening birt designer file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, birt

[image]

the -vm argument is pointing to correct jvm.dll file.

This happens when I try to open my eclipse.exe.

I tried removing the launcher library, it doesn't fix the issue.

Any help please ?

I just downloaded the BIRT design folder and unzipped it. I tried doing it again, thinking some extraction problem. din help.

Comment: Which version of BIRT do you use? From where did you download the "BIRT design folder". Your version seams to be from 2009. Did you try a new version of BIRT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused because of some variables in my environmental variables. the values were too high.